# Regex to match last sentence of a line

Tags: regex

Got some text:

```
[23/07 | DEV | FARO | QC Billable | #2032] Unable to Load label 
[30/07 | QC | ROLAWN ] Selling products as a bundle 
[11/08 | EST | QC BILLABLE | #2015 ISUOG ] On Demand website looping
[05/08 |  EST | ROLAWN | Problems with 'find a stockist'
[29/07 | DEV | QUBA] Blog comments loading to error
[24/07 | FROG | EST| QC BILLABLE #2033] Carousel banner not working correctly
```

I'm trying to match the last sentence at the end of each line so the matches are as follows:

```
Unable to Load label 
Selling products as a bundle 
On Demand website looping
Problems with 'find a stockist'
Blog comments loading to error
Carousel banner not working correctly
```

Unfortunately, I can't depend on the structure of the line to conform, but the information I'm trying to extract *should* always be the last sentence. I've tried quite a few different things, but I'm struggling here.

Comment: So we can't depend on matching the last bracket ']'?

Comment: There might be an easier solution to using a regular expression.  I can't make any more specific recommendations without knowing what environment for which this is intended.  Language?  Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is also some kind on no-word character before last sentence, try with:

```
[\w\s']+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uT7nA3/1)

Comment: @Jazcash you can change that to `\w[\w\s']+$` to avoid matching first space character (` `)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The answer above by m.cekiera `[\w\s']+$` is better.

```
](.+)$
```

Here's a pretty naive solution: https://regex101.com/r/yT8jJ7/1.

If you give more details about the actual structure it could be refined.